# Control with variable delay plus inverse relationship

Tags: pid-control, nonlinear-control

As we all (should) know, PID controllers are pretty bad when the system they control isn't linear.

In my case, I have a water heater and a pump. I want to control the pump so that the output is at a set temperature. (There's also a temperature sensor on the output.)

This is obviously an inverse relationship (double flow rate == half the temperature delta); also, the system's overall delay depends on the flow rate when the distance between heater and thermometer is significantly greater than zero.

Both problems are fatal for a PID controller that needs to both react reasonably quickly **and** be stable across most of its control range.

So. How should I go about controlling this? Inverting the PID output (i.e. 1/x, not 0-x) seems simple enough, that'd make the control effectively linear (or rather, I assume it will do so…), but the varying delay has me stumped.

Comment: Do you have flow rate measurement? or only temperature measurement? Are you familiar with techniques such as [MPC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Model_predictive_control)?

Comment: More generally, any delay in the loop pretty much forces you to limit the control loop gain (and thus limits the possible control bandwidth that you can attain). No way around it without adding an extra information to the system

Comment: If there is a way to estimate the temperature at the heater exit, from the history of the sensor/heater/flow data, then that should be the intermediate variable that is controlled. Note that this intermediate variable would still be subject to your (variable) delay.

Comment: @PeteW That's right; however, the problem remains that the delay is variable and depends on the PID output's recent history (again non-linear, but what else is new). So I am also looking for some way to modify the PID settings that at least allows me to interpolate the correct values somewhat more broadly than testing step functions every 10% of the control range.

Comment: Without knowing more about your control objectives and the system, I might try taking a representative semi-worst case. lets say like when the flow is 10% or 20% within its expected range, and tune for that. Obviously near 0% flow it's just not going to work. Higher flow on the other hand would reduce the delay, and should give you extra gain margin. Try just a PI controller to start with, and formulate it so your two parameters are gain and the time constant of the zero (ie in frequency domain). That'll make it a little easier to tune intuitively, hopefully

Comment: If it's really important not to overshoot, both PI nor PID often makes life harder for the designer, but that's another topic

Comment: And also... it'll be even more important than usual to gracefully handle saturation cases. Because every time the control output has to max out (eg any positive step), the flow goes to the minimum value, which means the system goes into its hardest-to-control regime of operation. rate limits on the plant may be advisable. this in turn suggests a good ARW strategy for the integrator is also important. It's an interesting setup!

Comment: Not necessarily fatal for a PID- you can always muck with its inputs (sensors don't have to be linear).  I'd hit it with my typical temperature and rate of temperature inputs- at desired temp but temp not going up = do not pump as you'd reduce the temperature presumably.  Key is what do you want to do if temperature is too high- you'd have hot stuff pumped unless you can control the heater.